# Console application with App.config

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a console application with App.config. It work fine when I run on my workstation. If I move the exe and exe.config file to the server nothing happens! Is it okay to just move exe and exe.config to a same folder and run the exe? Am i missing any other files? Please advise

Comment: You need to move all the dependencies, and the target machine must have the required version of .Net Framework installed

Comment: Are you using any external libraries? (.dll files) Does the target machine have .net framework installed?

Comment: .Net target version is same. All dependies means all the files under debug folder? @Amy

Comment: I have just referred one more dll. System.Configuration.dll to my project. Do i need to move anything to the server with regards to this?

Comment: No, a dependency is a DLL library your application requires to run.  Not all files in the debug folder are dependencies.  Have you not tried copying the entire folder?

Comment: I dont have any other dependencies. Is there something i need to do to refer the app config file while I call the exe

Comment: No.  I find it difficult to believe your software doesn't have any dependencies.  Provide enough information about your project.

Comment: I think I have some config issues. I just tried a simple console application and it does what it needs to on the servers. Thanks All.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably should not just be copying DLL and EXE files ad hoc, although if you are a clever developer you could probably figure out how to do it. An end user may not be so fortunate.

There are several established ways to deploy an application in a user-friendly fashion.  MSDN provides [guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htz3ee71.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on how to do it.

Probably the simplest way to distribute your application is to use [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx#clickonce).  Follow these steps:

1. Open the project in Visual Studio
2. Open the project properties
3. Click the "Publish" tab
4. Modify the defaults as desired, or leave them alone to publish your installation files in the `\publish` subdirectory of your project.
5. Click the "Publish Now" button
6. Visual Studio will check for dependencies and create a click-once installer for you, then open Windows Explorer to its location so you can copy the files.
7. Copy the files onto distribution media (ftp site, USB drive, network share, or something similar)
8. On the target machine, open the distribution media and run the installer exe.

Even if you don't plan on distributing the software, running through the publish procedure, opening the file ending with `.manifest`, and peeking at the XML will give you an idea what your dependencies are.

Comment: This worked. Clean way of pushing code to Server.